# Array getting converted to a string on server and being stored in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I created a `spring-boot` based java project, packaged it into a `WAR` and deployed it onto the server. It used `MySQL` as the database.

The structure of the table on my computer is

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | aid       | url  |
+----+-----------+------+
|  2 | 986542705 | 456  |
|  3 | 986542705 | 789  |
|  4 | 986542705 | 000  |
+----+-----------+------+
```

The structure of the same table on the server is

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | aid       | url         |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  2 | 986413172 | 456,789,000 |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

Since I am using `spring-boot` i have changed the `main()` from looking like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

to

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

while deploying on the server.

Then did `gradle war` on the directory and deployed the `war` onto `tomcat`

The `API` i am hitting is the same and i am passing an `array` as the parameter.

Comment: What's the error/question?

Comment: I want the same structure with the original data structure. Here the data structure is only changed.

Comment: Without some code how you get and store the data we are unable to help you

Comment: I'm confused, you're talking about a database mapping change, and then the second part of your question is about how you changed your application from a typical fat JAR configuration to a WAR configuration. What is your question exactly? Do you want to know how you build a WAR file or how you can handle multiple values in a same column?

Comment: No, the problem is a database mappng change. An Array passed via an API got changed to a string and then got saved to the database. I uploaded the WAR configuration asking whether that has anything to do with the Array to String change.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Will update soon